# when I pass html form data to local java spark server (main.java) the jquery can't find the url

Tags: java, jquery, rest, webserver

I need help passing some form data to main.java server (I am using java spark) using jquery
the server takes data from the url, so I want to send the data in the url

```
 <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>


<script> $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {

        var firstVar = $('#var1').val();
        var secondVar = $('#Var2').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/variabless",
             url: "/Variables/:Var1=firstVar&Var2=secondVar",

            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            },
        /*    error: function (err) {
            alert("fail");
            }*/

        });
```